# WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid - Spyder 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I am trying to print the file names in my directory using the following code:

```
dir_path = 'D:/#/#/#/#.json'     
for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
    print filename
    f = open(os.path.join(dir_path,filename), 'r')
```

but this error is displayed when running the code:

```
for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid: 'D:/#/#/#/#.json/*.*'
```

I am unsure what the `json/*.*` means in the error message, I am new to Python so apologies if this question is vague.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? list all `.json` files in which directory?

Comment: Yes, in the folder which contains all the .json files.

Comment: how is this folder called (full path) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear as to whether the directory `D:/#/#/#` contains any files in it other than JSON files, so I shall give two answers.  Hopefully one of them will apply to you:

1. **Directory contains only JSON files**

   In that case, simply remove the `/#.json` from the end of `dir_path`:

   ```
   dir_path = 'D:/#/#/#'     
   for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
       print filename
       f = open(os.path.join(dir_path,filename), 'r')
   ```
2. **Directory contains JSON files and other files that you want to exclude**

   In this situation it's best to use the Python [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module.

   The following should list all of the `.json` files in the folder `D:/#/#/#`:

   ```
   import glob

   dir_path = 'D:/#/#/#/*.json'     
   for filename in glob.glob(dir_path):
       print filename
       f = open(filename, 'r')
   ```

   Note that filenames returned by `glob.glob` include the directory path, so we don't use `os.path.join` on them.

[`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?#os.listdir) lists all files in the directory you give it.  However it seems you're not passing it the name of a directory, you're passing it the name of a file.  How can it possibly list all the files in a directory if you don't give it a directory?